# GridGain - Cache data from Oracle at startup and refresh cache

Tags: gridgain

I need to populate the cache at startup (referenced in this post [Add cache at runtime to GridGain / reconfigure GridGain at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23880168/add-cache-at-runtime-to-gridgain-reconfigure-gridgain-at-runtime)). I need to refresh the cache as some actions do change the data - how can I do it?

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://$SITEURL$/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `loadCache()` both for initial loading and for refresh.